# Trying to print randomly generated integer between 1 and 10

Tags: python

I'm attempting to generate 10 random integers, ranging from 1 to 10, and write them to a file. I can't figure out what argument I need to include in the write() function.  Any ideas?

```
import random

def main():
    rand_ints = open('mynumbers.txt', 'w')
    for count in range(10):
            print(random.randint(0,10))
        rand_ints.write(   '\n')
    rand_ints.close()

main()
```

Comment: You don't pick any numbers at random, nor you write the count to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write a text representation of a number to a file, you have to convert it to a string.

```
rand_ints.write(str(x) + '\n')
```

I'll leave you to look at the [`random` module docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) to figure out how to generate random numbers.

Comment: All comments were very helpful.  I understand the concept of generating a random number so that is not a problem, it was more converting it to the string and defining x.  Once that was figured out, only a single integer was randomly generated, e.g., 8 repeated, 6 repeated, etc.  I'll figure that one out.   Thank you.

Comment: @user3354066 make sure you don't seed the random number generator every time you use it.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you arnt picking any random numbers. Try `random.randint(1, 10)`
That peice of code generates a number from 1-10.

You then take that number `int randomNumber` and write it to the file as follows: 
`rand_ints.write(str(randomNumber) + '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import random ## imports the random module

## list comprehension, creates 10 random integers from 1 to 10 (as strings) 
## and puts them in a list
x = [str(random.randint(1,10)) for i in range(10)] 

myfile = open("somefile.txt", "w") ## opens your file for writing
for part in x: ## loops through your list of random numbers
    myfile.write(part + "\n") ## writes them to your list along with a new line
myfile.close()  ## closes your file
```

The problem with your code is that you were not actually using `random` to generate your random numbers, and then you were not writing any numbers, just newlines (`\n`) to your file